# OpenAI ChatGPT API pauses the rest of the code until it finishes processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

I am trying to integrate ChatGPT into a discord bot so I created the following function to receive a response from the GPT-3.5 Turbo model of ChatGPT, but when I call this function it causes the rest of the bot code to pause execution until it returns a response. The following code is located in a separate `.py` file(`responses.py`) in the same project path.

How can I stop it from interrupting the rest of the code?

```
async def DM_response(messages: str, message,username,user_id):
  #define OpenAI API Key for DM's 
  openai.api_key = "MY OPENAI KEY"
  if len(message.attachments) > 0:
      await message.author.send(await read_error_codes('manual_responses.txt', 1))
      return
  else:
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo", 
    max_tokens=150,
    temperature=0.1,
    messages = [{"role": "system", "content":"You are a helpful assistent",},
                {"role": "user", "content":"{}".format(messages),},
                ]
    )
    DMresponse = completion['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    DMresponse = DMresponse.replace('\n', '')
    return DMresponse
```

Here is the part of the code where I call the function:

```
import responses

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    print('Received message:', message)  # debug statement
    username = str(message.author)
    user_message = str(message.content)
    user_id = message.author.id
    print(message.content) # debug statement
    if not message.author == client.user:
        if len(message.attachments) >= 1 :
          return
        elif isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            response = await responses.DM_response(user_message,message,username,user_id)
            #response = await responses.reply_test()
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return
```

I tested if it was something with my await declaration or the fact that it was in a separate `.py` file using the following code, but during the 10-second sleep time the rest of the bot had no problem functioning.

```
            response = await responses.reply_test()
            await message.channel.send(response)
```

and here is the `reply_test` function it is referring to:

```
async def reply_test(): #debug statement
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    text = 'for testing purpouses'
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by creating a new task using asyncio library that processes the function completely separately. here is the updated part of the code that calls the function:

```
import discord
import asyncio
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    print('Received message:', message)  # debug statement
    username = str(message.author)
    user_message = str(message.content)
    user_id = message.author.id
    print(message.content)
    if not message.author == client.user:
        if len(message.attachments) >= 1 :
          return
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            task = asyncio.create_task(responses.DM_response(user_message,message,username,user_id))
            response = await task
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return
```